# Spring JDBCTemplates: execute a query with Join

Tags: sql, spring-jdbc

I'm developing an app for DB querying, using Spring Boot and JDBCTemplates.

The problem is this: if I have to ask the db on a single table, I have no problems. But, if I have a join, how can I perform this task?

More specifically, the SQL commands to create tables are these:

```
CREATE TABLE firewall_items 
(
    id       INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firewall_id      INT NOT NULL,
    date     DATE,
    src      VARCHAR(15),
    src_port INT,
    dst      VARCHAR(15),
    dst_port INT,
    protocol VARCHAR(4),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );

CREATE TABLE firewalls (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    info TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );
```

The correspondings java class are these:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class FirewallItems 
{
    private Date date;
    private String id;
    private String protocol;
    private String src;
    private String dst;
    private String src_port;
    private String dst_port;
    private String firewall_id;


    public FirewallItems() {}


    public FirewallItems(Date data, String identificativo, String protocollo, String sorgente, String destinazione,
            String porta_sorgente, String porta_destinazione, String firewall_id) 
    {
        super();
        this.date = data;
        this.id = identificativo;
        this.protocol = protocollo;
        this.src = sorgente;
        this.dst = destinazione;
        this.src_port = porta_sorgente;
        this.dst_port = porta_destinazione;
        this.firewall_id = firewall_id;
    }

    /**
     * Return the date of the report
     * @return date
     */
    public Date getDate() 
    {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * Set the date of the report
     * @param date the report's date
     */
    public void setDate(Date date) 
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    /**
     * Return the id of the report
     * @return id
     */
    public String getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the id of the report
     * @param id the report's id
     */
    public void setId(String id) 
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Return the protocol cecked by report
     * @return protocol
     */
    public String getProtocol() 
    {
        return protocol;
    }

    /**
     * Set the protocol cecked by report
     * @param protocol
     */
    public void setProtocol(String protocol) 
    {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    /**
     * Return the source of firewall's drop
     * @return Src
     */
    public String getSrc() 
    {
        return src;
    }

    /**
     * Set the source of firewall's drop
     * @param src the firewall's source drop
     */
    public void setSrc(String src) 
    {
        this.src = src;
    }

    /**
     * Return the firewall's destionation drop
     * @return dst
     */
    public String getDst() 
    {
        return dst;
    }

    /**
     * Set the firewall's destination drop
     * @param dst the firewall's destination drop 
     */
    public void setDst(String dst) 
    {
        this.dst = dst;
    }

    /**
     * Return the source's port
     * @return src_port
     */
    public String getSrc_port() 
    {
        return src_port;
    }

    /**
     * Set the source's port
     * @param src_port the source's port
     */
    public void setSrc_port(String src_port) 
    {
        this.src_port = src_port;
    }

    /**
     * Return the destination's port
     * @return dst_port
     */
    public String getDst_port() 
    {
        return dst_port;
    }

    /**
     * Set the destination's port
     * @param dst_port the destination's port
     */
    public void setDst_port(String dst_port) 
    {
        this.dst_port = dst_port;
    }

    /**
     * Return the id of firewall associated to report
     * @return firewall_id
     */
    public String getFirewall_id() 
    {
        return firewall_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the id of firewall associated to report
     * @param firewall_id the id of firewall associated to report
     */
    public void setFirewall_id(String firewall_id) 
    {
        this.firewall_id = firewall_id;
    }   
}

public class Firewall 
{
    private String id;
    private String ip;
    private String info;
    private String name;


    /**
     * Empty constructor, which instantiates a Firewall specimen without setting default values
     */
    public Firewall() {}

    /**
     * Constructor instantiating a Firewall specimen specifying its initial values
     * 
     * @param id the firewall's id code
     * @param ip the firewall's ip code
     * @param info the info about firewall
     * @param name firewall's name
     */
    public Firewall(String id, String ip, String info, String nome) 
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.info = info;
        this.name = nome;
    }

    /**
     * Return the firewall's id
     * @return id
     */
    public String getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Set firewall's id
     * @param id the firewall's id
     */
    public void setId(String id) 
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Return the firewall's ip
     * @return ip
     */
    public String getIp() 
    {
        return ip;
    }

    /**
     * Set firewall's ip
     * @param ip the firewall's ip
     */
    public void setIp(String ip) 
    {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    /**
     * Return firewall's info
     * @return info
     */
    public String getInfo() 
    {
        return info;
    }

    /**
     * Set firewall's info
     * @param info firewall's info fields
     */
    public void setInfo(String info) 
    {
        this.info = info;
    }

    /**
     * Return firewall's name
     * @return name
     */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set firewall's name
     * @param name firewall's name
     */
    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The constraint is that firewall_Items.firewall_id = firewall.id (so, these are the variables that i must use to perform join).

Now, if i want perform this query:

```
SELECT info, src
FROM firewalls, firewall_items
WHERE firewall_items.firewall_id = firewalls.id;
```

How my java code must be, using jdbctemplate?
Should i add to firewall class a collection to collect object of FirewallsItems, like an ArrayList?

Note1: i must use jdbctemplate project specifications. I can't use Hibernate or other instruments.

Note2: I know what rowmapper and resultset are, i regolary use them with query on a single table. What i nedd is to understand how to use them for a query with join, like that of the example.

Thanks a lot in advance for response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use the JOIN keyword to join your tables before you query them.
Like so:

```
String query= "SELECT firewall_items.src, firewalls.info 
FROM firewall_items 
JOIN firewalls 
ON firewall_items.firewalls_id = firewalls.id"

List<Item> items = jdbcTemplate.query(
          query, 
          new MapSqlParameterSource(), 
          new FirewallInfoRowMapper()
          );
```

Where Item is your retrieved object. You decide what that is.

Look at [this](http://www.sqlcourse2.com/joins.html) article for more info

EDIT:

In response to your further inquiry. Above is the amended usage of jdbcTemplate, below you can find the classes you need.  This requires you to have [Spring](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/).
I've assumed that if you're using jdbcTemplate you already have Spring.

Below is a cheat sheet, but please look at [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/) site and learn more about querying databases with java Spring and jdbcTemplates.

The correct implementation for a row mapper is like so :

```
public class FirewallInfoRowMapper implements RowMapper<FirewallInfo>{
  @Override
  public FirewallInfo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException{
    return new FirewallInfo(rs.getString("src"), rs.getString("info")) 
}
}


public class FirewallInfo{
  private String src;
  private String info;

  public FirewallInfo(String src, String info){
    this.src = src;
    this.info = info;
  }

  {}<<< Getters and Setters Here
}
```

Comment: I recommend you to follow 1) standart Java field naming convension; 2) use Lombok and don't generate getters/setter manually; 3) use BeanRowPropertyMapper instead of obvious mapping in RowMapper implementation

Comment: First of all, thanks for the responses.

My problem is not how to formulate the String query; I had already thought to use join in it.
My difficulties are how to implement correctly, for the case in question, the RowMapper and how to choose a good type for List<Item>.

Comment: Thnks Vladislav, it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

I know its late. There aren't a lot of good tutorial out there so incase someone else needs to know how to execute join query with spring and jdbc template. This is the way I did mine.
First ensure to import the following jars in your dao class like so

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
```

Then in your FirewallDao class, do something like

```
public List<Firewall> getData(){
    return template.query("SELECT firewalls.info, firewall_items.src FROM firewalls INNER JOIN firewall_items ON firewall_items.firewall_id = firewalls.id",new RowMapper<Firewall>(){
        public Firewall mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
            Firewall f =new Firewall();
            f.setInfo(rs.getString(1));
            f.setSrc(rs.getString(2));
            return f;
        }
    });
}
```

In you controller, something like

```
@Autowired
FirewallDao dao;

@RequestMapping("/viewinfo")
public ModelAndView viewinfo(){
    List<Firewall> list=dao.getData();
    return new ModelAndView("viewinfo","list",list);
}
```

in ur view, do something like

```
<table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">
<tr><th>Info</th><th>Src</th></th><th>Edit</th></tr>
<c:forEach var="f" items="${list}"> 
<tr>
<td>${f.info}</td>
<td>${f.src}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```